# Emit change or bind to model not working

Tags: html, angular

I am currently learning the way components are suppose to be used and when they should be created.

I have learnt that for example when creating a Task List the best way to go about this would be to have a stateless wrapper and then a stateful task list item and checkbox components. (See Below)

[Example of Task stateful and stateless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt1Zh.png)

The issue I am currently having is figuring out the best practice on the issue and putting it into practice.

1. Emitting the (change) event from the checkbox to the stateless components and then setting the Model.Done flag to True or False.
2. Binding the Model.Done to the Checkbox component so that it will change automatically.

Example of 2:

Task.component

```
<div fxFlex='20' style="background: #C3C3C3">
  <app-task-list-item *ngFor="let task of tasks" [task]="task"></app-task-list-item>  
</div>
```

Task-List-Item.component

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <p style="padding-right: 2em;">{{task.date}}</p>
  <p style="padding-right: 2em;">{{task.description}}</p>
  <app-task-list-checkbox [checked]="task.done"></app-task-list-checkbox>
</div>
```

Task-List-Checkbox.component

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="checked">
```

The question I am asking is:

1. Would you emit the change of the checkbox to the stateless component?
2. Would you create a checkbox component or add that to the Task-List-Item.component?

Comment: in the title of your question is see Emit Change not working .. i can't see any `EventEmitter` in your code , what did you try ?

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID The reason that is in the title is due to one of the questions that I asked regarding is EventEmitter the best way to go about the component structure.

Comment: so if i understand well , your goal is to detect  the checkbox change in `Task.component`  passing by `Task-List-Item.component` ?

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID I would also like to know if creating a component for the checkbox element is worth doing as well?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to emit anything to your stateless component. Just use two-way data binding with your checkbox. Because of object reference, each task in array tasks will have its done property changed when you toggle your checkbox. You don't also have to create a component for a single checkbox, just put it into your Task-List-Item.component

Task-List-Item.component:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <p style="padding-right: 2em;">{{task.date}}</p>
    <p style="padding-right: 2em;">{{task.description}}</p>
    <input [(ngModel)]="task.done" type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I listened to a class online that said the Checkbox might have animations ... events etc and therefore to put in own component? Do you not think that is the correct way to go?

Comment: I don't think but if you really need to do these animations, event,... you can wrapp it in its component and it will still working with two-way binding on the checkbox

Comment: How do you pass the task.done to the checkbox if its inside another component?

Comment: You pass it as an input of the component wrapping the checkbox